# Why is the relation $R = \{(a, b), (a, c)\}$ over $X = \{a, b, c\}$ transitive?

Tags: relations

I know it is not complete and I know it is asymmetric. But how is it transitive? The textbook says it is transitive...

Instead, I used a different example of transitive, asymmetric, and not complete, which is $X = \{a, b, c, d\}$ with $R = \{(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)\}$.

Comment: It is indeed transitive.  The reason being, for any collection of elements, $x,y,z$ (some of these are allowed to be equal) whenever you have $xRy$ and $yRz$ you must also have $xRz$.  In your specific example there do not exist any three elements $x,y,z$ even allowing repeats such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ simultaneously.  As a result, it is vacuously transitive.  This is the same reason why the relation $\{(a,b)\}$ is transitive.  See [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: A different wording of transitivity in terms of graph theory: any directed path from point $a$ to point $b$ that can be made in two (*or more*) steps must also be traversable in a single step.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget about vacuous truths...!

Comment: As an aside, if you are looking for the smallest example of a transitive antisymmetric incomplete relation, the [empty relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690482/is-the-relation-r-emptyset-is-it-reflexive-symmetric-and-transitive-why) on the set $\{1\}$ would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, this is indeed a transitive relation. This is because the definition of transitivity requires "$xRy \land yRz$" to hold; however, for the given relation, this never holds, and thus via a vacuous argument the relation is transitive.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*

Answer (score 0):

Another view on this.
Let $R\subseteq X\times X$. Define $R^2=\{(a,c)\,|\, \exists b\in X.(a,b),(b,c)\in R\}$.

By definition $"R \text{ is transitive}"\Leftrightarrow R^2\subseteq R$.

In your case (in the title) $R^2=\varnothing$.

For your second relation we have $R^2=\{(a,c)\}$.